# Is the dot product of spins the only way to create a scalar (Hamiltonian) invariant under spin rotation?

Tags: condensed-matter, hilbert-space, angular-momentum, quantum-spin, spin-chains

I wanted to generalize the result for the following question for four spins 1/2: [Most general form of a spin rotation invariant Hamiltonian?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/744906/most-general-form-of-a-spin-rotation-invariant-Hamiltonian).
Assume that we have a Hilbert space for four spins $(\vec{S}_1,\vec{S}_2,\vec{S}_3,\vec{S}_4)$ and we want to create an object $H:=H(\vec{S}_1,\vec{S}_2,\vec{S}_3,\vec{S}_4)$ that is invariant under spin rotation, i. e., $[H,\vec{S}_T]=0$, with $\vec{S}_T=\sum_{i=1}^4\vec{S}_i$. What is the most general form of $H$?

My intuition tells me that
$H=\sum_{i=1}^4 \left \{H_1(\vec{S}_i)+\sum_{j=i+1}^4\left [H_2(\vec{S}_i,\vec{S}_j)+\sum_{k=j+1}^4H_3(\vec{S}_i,\vec{S}_j,\vec{S}_k)\right]\right\}+H_4(\vec{S}_1,\vec{S}_2,\vec{S}_3,\vec{S}_4)$ with $H_n$ the most general form to create a scalar out of $n$ spins. For instance, $H_1(\vec{S}_i)=H_1(\vec{S}_i\cdot \vec{S}_i$) (i.e., proportional to the identity) using spectral decomposition as in the example for two spins.
Similarly, we know that for two spins $H_2(\vec{S}_i,\vec{S}_j)=H_2(\vec{S}_i\cdot \vec{S}_j$). For three spins, I would expect $H_3(\vec{S}_i,\vec{S}_j,\vec{S}_k)=H_3(\vec{S}_i\cdot(\vec{S}_j\times\vec{S}_k))=H_3(\vec{S}_i\cdot\vec{S}_j,\vec{S}_i\cdot\vec{S}_k,\vec{S}_j\cdot\vec{S}_k)$. The last equality comes from $2i(\vec{S}_i\cdot(\vec{S}_j\times\vec{S}_k))=4(\vec{S}_i\cdot\vec{S}_j)(\vec{S}_i\cdot\vec{S}_k)-\vec{S}_j\cdot\vec{S}_k$. $H_4$ should be dependent on the dot products between all pairs of spins. Ultimately, this would say that $H$ only depends on the dot products between the spins involved. This form of $H$ is immediately rotation invariant, yet I don't see how to show that if the Hamiltonian is rotation invariant, it must depend only on dot products between pairs.
Does somebody know how to show this?

Comment: How did you get the equality $i(\vec{S}_i \cdot  (\vec{S}_j \times \vec{S}_k)) = (\vec{S}_i \vec{S}_j)(\vec{S}_i \vec{S}_k) - \vec{S}_j \vec{S}_k$?

Comment: Hi, I made a mistake in this equality with some constants. It is corrected now. The identity is demonstrated with the commutator and anticommutator of the Pauli matrices for a single site. $\{\sigma_i,\sigma_j\}=2\delta_{i,j}$ and $[\sigma_i,\sigma_j]=2i\sum_k\epsilon_{ijk}\sigma_k$. You start by expanding $(\vec{A}\cdot \vec{\sigma})(\vec{B}\cdot \vec{\sigma})$, then replace the anticommutator and then the commutator.

Comment: The indices $i, j, k$ refer to the sites, not to the spin components. In your notation, $\vec{S}_i$ and $\vec{S}_j$ commute for $i\ne j$. I think this equality is incorrect.

Comment: I think that $\hat{H} = (\vec{S}_1 \cdot [\vec{S}_2 \times \vec{S}_3])$ is a counterexample to your claim that rotationally invariant Hamiltonian must depend only on products between spins.

Comment: Anikin, for the demonstration of the equation that relates the double dot product with the cross product, the indices correspond to the $x$, $y$, and $z$ directions. This demonstration is done for any $\vec{A}$ and $\vec{B}$. The latter is sufficient since, as you pointed out, the elements of the spin operators of different sites commute with each other. Consequently, $\vec{A}$ and $\vec{B}$ can be replaced by spin operators of distinct sites. Thus, the "counterexample" you propose is just an example of my claim.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding, now I see it. Thank you!